Powershell to run macros in Revit
I am experiencing some issues with trying to initiate a macro through power shell for Revit.  In Excel it seems rather simple based on this
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\fso -Include *.xls, *.xlsm -Recurse
Foreach($file in $excelFiles)
{
   $workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($file.fullname)
   $worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)
   $excel.Run("CreateChart")
   $workbook.save()
   $workbook.close()
}
$excel.quit()

However Revit.Application is not an object on my computer even though the executable is there.
Due to Revit changing their API in 2024 we have a mirroring issue that I am trying to work around.  If any of you could help me figure this out I would be forever in your debt.
here is a reference to a comment so you do not have to scroll further.
@logicaldiagram I have the macro written. I just need Powershell to open the document run the macro and close the document. To give more of a highlight to what is happening Autodesk's Revit changed their api in 2024 which caused a major flaw in our feature. What is needed now is to utilize a post command that Revit has today (this is what the Macro does) however post commands can not run until all the code has completed. So the idea of putting this in a loop is out of the question
When trying this I am unable to get the script to work

I think the Revit website must have some java scripts running that you must wait for the scripts to complete.  The only solution I have used in the past is to loop on the webpage until a object turns from null to a real value indicating the java script has completed.

@jdweng Revit is a desktop application so I am confused to why the webpage would matter?

Many desktop applications make a HTTP connections.  The server of the connection is called a website.   The difference between a browser connection and a http client connection is the browser displays results while the http client doesn't display the data.

As I replied in my answer to your question in the Revit API discussion forum on Powershell to run macros in Revit:
You cannot simply drive Revit from outside like Excel. The Revit API requires a valid Revit API context to execute. Such context is only provided within the event handlers of Revit API events. Such handlers can only be registered from a Revit add-in, which needs to be loaded into a running session of Revit.exe. This behaviour has not changed in recent years, and this description applies to all active versions of Revit, at least the last 10 or 15 or so.
You can drive Revit from outside by first loading an add-in implementing  an external event and then raising that event from your Powershell script.
The Building Coder provides a whole host of articles on how you can use Idling and external events for modeless access and driving Revit from outside.
By the way, I just answered a related question on how to do PostableCommand execution without closing Windows Form that explains the situation further, from another point of view.
